# Relations between Whittaker functions/W algebras and Stokes data/resurgence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, big-list, geometric-representation-theory, w-algebras

**Skippable background:** A *Whittaker function* is more or less a function on a flag manifold which is twisted-invariant for the action of a unipotent subgroup. E.g. consider functions $f$ on $\mathbf{P}^1$ which are equivariant for the action of $\mathbf{C}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&z\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$, twisted by the character $\psi$ sending $\psi:\begin{pmatrix}1&z\\&1\end{pmatrix}\mapsto e^z$, i.e.
$$f(z+x)\ =\ \psi(z)f(x) \hspace{10mm}\rightsquigarrow\hspace{10mm} f(x)\ =\ \text{const}.e^{x}.$$
*W algebra* is a name for a similar structure in representation theory/physics, in this case corresponding to the D-module $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1}e^x$ generated by the Whittaker function.

---

Notice that $e^x$ has an *irregular* singularity at infinity, so you should probably consider its Stokes data. Moreover, there are papers with titles like [Higher Airy structures, W algebras and topological recursion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08738) (n.b. Airy functions are prototypical examples of functions with irregular singularities).

---

**My question is:** What are the expected relations between W algebra type structures and Stokes data type structures (e.g. recursion/resurgence)? Is there a good toy example to consider?